# Heroku scheduler rake tasks sidebyside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have about six Rake tasks I want to run around 4AM every morning. The issue is,  they won't run at the same time.

I don't have a worker dyno switched on as I thought this was just wasting money. I'm not 100% sure why this work dyno actually exists.

How do I make the rake tasks all run at the same time? Would switching on the worker dyno make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Having them all run concurrently is tough with just the Heroku scheduler. One dyno and Rake tasks won't do it. You'll need to use a threaded background job of some type. I have used sidekiq the most and like it the best.

There are a couple of moving parts to this but you'll basically need a worker dyno to run [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)  and you can set the concurrency to 6 and then run them via a cron task such as whenever or [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork).

I think this is the best way to handle your problem if you truly need them to run at very close to the same time. Exactly the same time isn't going to happen.